# Uploading videos to Youtube adds a background to it

Tags: youtube, youtube-channels

I have uploaded a video to youtube. A screenshot looks like this.[image: Original video]

When it is on Youtube it looks like this

[image: Youtube video]

What has happened is that this single coloured background has been added by youtube or somehow in the uploading process as it is not in the original video. I wish to stop this from happening and only upload my video, contained within the white frame. Can anybody explain what is happening and possibly how to prevent this?